# Typo3 tt_news disabled date

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I am facing problem with tt_news in typo3 version 6.2.11.
I can not set date above 2020 year. I can set till 31.12.2020 and after that all dates are disabled.
I have taken 2 screenshot of it. Any hint or solution would help me.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OpdU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tt_news has a hardcoded maximum for the end date, which in the version you're using is 31-12-2020. The best advice is to upgrade. TYPO3 6.2 isn't supported anymore.

However, if you need a quick fix,  you'll need to change it in the TCA file of tt_news. You can find that in `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/tca.php` or `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/Configuration/TCA/tt_news.php` depending on which version of the extension you're using.

This file contains an array with the configuration of the fields for this table. For the field `endtime` it should contain something like this:

```
'range' => [
  'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 31, 12, 2020)
]
```

You'll need to change that date.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the solution. Right now i do not have server ftp access. I tried TS config but it did not work.

Comment: Did you set it in a TypoScript template or in the TSConfig field of the (root) page? It should be in the TSConfig field.

Comment: i added it in TSConfig field (one level above from where tt_new are located).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the line. It should be `upper`, not `max`. I've edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: I tried it but still not working.  check image https://ibb.co/DtGK2p7

Comment: I just checked. Apparently this is not one of the values you can overwrite with TS config. Then your only option is changing it in `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/tca.php` or `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/Configuration/TCA/tt_news.php in newer versions. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The range-array occurs twice in tca.php. The first occurrence should be updated

```
$TCA['tt_news']['columns']['endtime']['config']['range']['upper']
```

At the next one you can do as well

```
$TCA['tt_news_cat']['columns']['endtime']['config']['range']['upper']
```

My fault was to change the latter one without effect.